# BeautifulSoup duplicated find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have html in a list called `html`.

```
html = [u'<body bgcolor="#F2F2F2" lang=EN-GB link=blue vlink=purple style=\'tab-interval:36.0pt\'>\r\n\r\n<div class=WordSection1>\r\n\r\n<p class=MsoNormal style=\'margin-left:120.0pt;text-indent:-120.0pt;tab-stops:120.0pt;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none\'>\r\n<b><span style=\'font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri; color:black\'>From:<span style=\'mso-tab-count:1\'></span></span></b>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n']
```

I parse it through beautifulsoup like so:

```
for i in email:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(i, "html.parser")

    for i in soup(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
        i.extract()

    scrape_selected_tags = soup.find_all(["a", "abbr", "acronym", "address", "b", "big", "br", "caption",
                                          "cite", "code", "datalist", "dd", "dfn", "dir", "dl", "dt",
                                          "div", "em", "figcaption", "footer", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4",
                                          "h5", "h6", "header", "i", "img", "iframe", "label", "legend",
                                          "li", "mark", "ol", "p", "pre", "q", "small", "source",
                                          "strike", "strong", "span", "sub" , "sup", "table", "tbody",
                                          "td", "th", "time", "title", "tt", "tr", "u", "ul", "video",
                                          "wbr"], recursive = False)
```

However, it seems to be duplicating the output? This is what I get when i print `scrape_selected_tags`:

```
[<div class="WordSection1">\n<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left:120.0pt;text-indent:-120.0pt;tab-stops:120.0pt;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none">\n<b><span style='font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri; color:black'>From:<span style="mso-tab-count:1"></span></span></b>\n</p></div>, <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left:120.0pt;text-indent:-120.0pt;tab-stops:120.0pt;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none">\n<b><span style='font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri; color:black'>From:<span style="mso-tab-count:1"></span></span></b>\n</p>, <b><span style='font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri; color:black'>From:<span style="mso-tab-count:1"></span></span></b>, <span style='font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri; color:black'>From:<span style="mso-tab-count:1"></span></span>, <span style="mso-tab-count:1"></span>]
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to stop this?

Comment: It is `recursive`, not `recurisve`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks! but now i get an empty ouput...

Comment: I'm not surprised, since with `recursive=False`, you only search the top level of the HTML.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem even without `recursive=False` i still have duplicates..

Comment: those are not duplicates, these are different HTML elements, but some are the parents of others. Like `<a><b></b></a>` and `<b></b>` can be in the list. The first one is the `<a>` tag with its child, the second is a reference to the `<b>` tag.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, so surely `recursive=False` would just output the top level HTML without considering the child tags?